# Are $R$ and $\mathbb R×\mathbb R$ similar?

Tags: order-theory

Are $ R$ and $\mathbb R×\mathbb R$ similar ? With antilexicographic order
$(  (a,b)<(c,d)\iff( b < d)\vee (b=d\text{ and }a <c))$ . Two sets are similar if there exists a bijection between them which keeps the order in sets.
I think they aren't but can't find a similarity invariant.
They should differ in continuity (every nonempty subset with an upper bound has a supremum ), but how do I prove that for $\mathbb R×\mathbb R$?
Edit: Thanks for the hint, I proved it.

Comment: Efforts for trying to solve the problem should be included in the post since it's way too easy to claim that one has tried but failed.

Comment: Accepting an answer that has helped you is an important part of the stackexchange ethic. If you don't accept helpful answers, who will want to bother with answering your questions?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The set $\{ (x,0) | x \in \mathbb R \}$ is bounded and in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$. Show that it doesn't have a supremum.